# Replace Exact String in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

This is the string I got:

```
http://sdsadasd/time/time.jsp?tp=&a
```

Now I want to replace the second **time.jsp** with **java.jsp** but **not** the first "time"?

How can I achieve it? I already tried this but it did not work:

```
replaceAll("\\btime.jsp"", "java.jsp");
```

Thanks.

Comment: _did not work_ is pretty useless. How did it behave? What did you expect it to do? Why did you expect it to do that?

Comment: Your `replaceAll` works (I guess your original is without the double ""). Note `replaceAll` does not modify your string but returns a new one.

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regex syntax. If you are interested in replacing literals use `replace`. Also remember that Strings are immutable so you can't change them, that is why `replace` returns new, modified string instead which you need to store.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: I think the question is rather clear and why it should do that should be up to me. Besides, I already got help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String result = "http://sdsadasd/time/time.jsp?tp=&a".replaceFirst("time\\.jsp", "java.jsp");
```

Or using the good friend [ApacheCommon](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) StringUtils...

```
String result = StringUtils.replaceOnce("http://sdsadasd/time/time.jsp?tp=&a", "time.jsp", "java.jsp");
```

For example, you can do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = "http://sdsadasd/time/time.jsp?tp=&a".replaceFirst("time\\.jsp", "java.jsp");
    System.out.println(result);
}

// Print: 
http://sdsadasd/time/java.jsp?tp=&a
```

Comment: `StringUtils` is not a class from Java's standard library. From which library is this class?

Comment: RE StringUtils: Only if you have Apache commons lang on the classpath

Comment: There is a `/` before _time_ which is a word boundary, so `\b` should work.

Comment: @rici thanks a lot. I removed the answer because I liked yours more than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
replaceAll("time.jsp", "java.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace *only* the second occurance of "time.jsp".

```
Try the following:

    boolean replace = false;
    int index = myString.indexOf("time.jsp");
    while(index != -1) {
        String substr = myString.substring(index);
        if(replace) {
            //do your replacement
        }
        index = myString.indexOf("time.jsp", index + 1);
    }
```

I didn't compile this, but it is a general solution you can use!